# Creating a website with search filters like amazon and Ebay. Is it possible?

Tags: search, navigation

I want to create a website which will be a search based. It will allow users to narrow down results based on categories and tags. The website is not a shopping website but will be a collection of articles. The user will narrow down the results using categories and sub categories and various types. I want to know that is this kind of functionality obtained from Drupal. I am using Joomla and its not allowing me to do what I want.

Comment: You can use "views exposed filter" for searching between contents, and you can put the search filter in block as well.. very useful.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementing a functionality for which only a informal description is provide. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I take you are expecting the answer to explain you exactly how to achieve this. The question is too broad to be acceptable. If you were expecting just a yes/no answer, then the question would not be much helpful for future readers, and should still be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [Solr](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) as that supports faceted searching.

It is rather complicated to set up though if you are using your own search server.